# Deleting records in LINQ with foreign keys - invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq, delete-row

I have a simple database:

```
ARTICLE
----------
ArticleId (PK),
ArticleTitle
..other stuff...

USER-ARTICLE
------------
ArchiveId (PK),
UserId,
ArticleId
..other stuff...
```

The `articleId`'s are foreign keys.

I want to be able to delete a user article row by `UserArticleId` using the following code,

```
UserArticle myobjtodelete = PersonalArchiveDb.UserArticles.Single(ua => ua.ArchiveId == 3);
PersonalArchiveDb.UserArticles.DeleteOnSubmit(myobjtodelete);
PersonalArchiveDb.SubmitChanges();
```

<sup>(Yes I'm aware I can do the statement inside the delete rather than retrieving the object, it was for debugging purposes to make sure the object definitely exists - it does.)</sup>

When the debugger hits the `SubmitChanges()` line, I get a runtime error:

> Specified cast is not valid.

Here is the stack trace,

> at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager
>       .StandardIdentityManager
>       .SingleKeyManager`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, V& v)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[]
>   keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType
>   type, Object[] keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type,
>   Object[] keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc,
>   Object instance)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()    at
>   Driver_SOC_ASO.Controls.PersonalArchive.ArchiveListing.grdArchive_RowDeleting(Object
>   sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) in
>   C:\work\Driver.Net\Driver-SOC-ASO\Driver-SOC-ASO\Controls\PersonalArchive\ArchiveListing.ascx.cs:line
>   78    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowDeleting(GridViewDeleteEventArgs
>   e)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow
>   row, Int32 rowIndex)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I am at a loss, any ideas?

Comment: Your sample code uses "ArchiveId" rather than "ArticleId" - in your original description, do you mean "Archive" instead of "Article"?

Comment: Yeah sorry, there UserArticleId == ArchiveId, poor naming i know

Will edit

Answer (score 1):

This may be an example of this [bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=351358), which Microsoft says is fixed in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

try setting ON CASCADE DELETE for `ArticleId`

Answer (score 0):

In your dbml, check to see if there is incorrect an association b/w Article and UserArticle.